# Session when user logs in PHP

Tags: php, session

i'm developing a website where a user can log in but i can't get it to work i've tried so much but it dosen't help... i can't find any mistakes in my code but maybe you can:)
Here's my code:

```
   <?php
require_once 'core/database/connect.php';
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $usname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    $paswd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, name FROM users WHERE                           username = '$usname'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $usid = $row['0'];
    $dbUsname = $row['1'];
    $dbPassword = $row['2'];
    $dbName = $row['3'];
    if ($usname == $dbUsname && md5($paswd) == $dbPassword) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbUsname;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $usid;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $dbName;
        header("Location: user.php");
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops, that username or password was incorrect. Please try again. Be aware of capital letters!</h2>";
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: General note: do yourself a favour and don't use the `mysql_*` functions when writing new code. They are becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: Hello, As Gerald Schneider wrote, mysql_* functions is deprecated from for new versions, so just check it out your version, phpinfo() will get your the full detail of your PHP, mysql, apache details and otehr details as well. so just check it out first and then try with mysqli_* or PDO connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use quotes when retrieving from the mysql row values:

```
$usid = $row['0'];
$dbUsname = $row['1'];
$dbPassword = $row['2'];
$dbName = $row['3'];
```

try instead:

```
$usid = $row[0];
$dbUsname = $row[1];
$dbPassword = $row[2];
$dbName = $row['3'];
```

This will reference the columns in their order whereas the way you are using it will reference the column name.

Answer (score 0):

why you start session again and Don't use quotes when retrieving from the mysql row values
Also better solution you need to turn on notices and errors in your php.ini and debug code line by line
try

```
<?php
require_once 'core/database/connect.php';
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_http_output( "UTF-8" );
ob_start("mb_output_handler");
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $usname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
    $paswd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, name FROM users WHERE username = '$usname'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $usid = $row[0];
    $dbUsname = $row[1];
    $dbPassword = $row[2];
    $dbName = $row[3];
    if ($usname == $dbUsname && md5($paswd) == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $dbUsname;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $usid;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $dbName;
        header("Location: user.php");
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Oops, that username or password was incorrect. Please try again. Be aware of capital letters!</h2>";
    }
    }
    else {
      echo 'NO record found';
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: It can be assumed that the password is stored as an md5 hash in the database. No need to double hash.

Comment: i have tried removing the qoutes but i can't log in!

Answer (score 0):

```
$row['0']
```

Would work if you were working with an associated array of the form `"namedKey" => someValue` but you want to fetch the first value `$row[0]`, second value `$row[1]`, etc.

Remove the quote marks and you should be fine.

Note that you are using `mysql_*` which is deprecated and highly insecure. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Also note that you are not escaping your input nor are you using prepared statements, meaning that it's easy to inject your database and even drop it, both of which are recommended but the latter would be enough.